# How do I make a Primeng Generic Group Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, primeng

My object:

```
users = [
  {id: 1, name: "name1", company: "com1"},
  {id: 2, name: "name2", company: "com2"},
  {id: 3, name: "name3", company: "com1"},
  {id: 4, name: "name4", company: "com2"},
  {id: 5, name: "name5", company: "com3"},
]
```

For primeng dropdown I need to convert it to a preferred object,
how do I do it with angular 2 as follows.

The object I want to make:

```
[
  {
    label: 'com1', 
    items: [
      {id: 1, name: "name1", company: "com1"},
      {id: 3, name: "name3", company: "com1"}
     ]
  },
 {
    label: 'com2', 
    items: [
      {id: 2, name: "name2", company: "com2"},
      {id: 4, name: "name4", company: "com2"}
     ]
  },
  {
    label: 'com3', 
    items: [
      {id: 5, name: "name5", company: "com3"},
     ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) combination.

Documentation states for `reduce()`:

> The reduce() method executes a reducer function (that you provide) on each element of the array, resulting in a single output value.

And for `find()`:

> The find() method returns the value of the first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function.

Please find a working example below:

```js
const users = [
  {id: 1, name: "name1", company: "com1"},
  {id: 2, name: "name2", company: "com2"},
  {id: 3, name: "name3", company: "com1"},
  {id: 4, name: "name4", company: "com2"},
  {id: 5, name: "name5", company: "com3"},
];

const result = users.reduce((a, {id, name, company}) => {
  const found = a.find(e => e.label === company);

  if (found) {
    found.items.push({
      id, name, company
    });
  } else {
    a.push({
      label: company,
      items: [{id, name, company}],
    });
  }
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

**+1 suggestion:**

It is totally up to you how and where you want to use the destructuring statement but consider the following. I was thinking also once providing the solution here which is when to destructure the current item for `reduce()`. If I would use `(a,c) => {}` for `reduce()` instead of `(a, {id, name, company}) => {}` then in the array's push lines I could use `{...c}` instead.

I hope that helps!

Comment: `reduce` is nice and this answer uses great ES6+ syntax.

Comment: @IraklisGkougkousis Thanks! One thing what I was thinking if it is worth to use destructuring statement in reduce arguments case for this scenario. If I would use `(a,c) => {}` for `reduce` then in the array's `push` lines I could use `{...c}` instead. But I guess it is just a matter of decision in this case.

Comment: I think the syntax is superfluous in this case. `(a,c) => {}` is what I would use, but this is just personal preference. In fact, I like that answers like yours highlight them, since a lot of people don't even know they exist.

Comment: I need to convert to -> SelectItemGroup


`
 "items": [ 
   { "id": 2, "name": "name2", "company": "com2" }
  ]
`

to 


`
[
            {
                label: 'com2', 
                items: [
                    {label: 'name2', value: '2'},
         
                ]
            }
        ];
`